# previous row all tr td selectbox values is empty?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

i want to check in table  tbody every tr >td first select box option value is not empty in jquery I WANT TO CHECK previous all tr>td first select box ibs not empty 
 Notes: i am using as tbody row  every tr >td first is a select box

Help Me

this is my jquery code

```
$(document).on("change", ".cmplregimem .cmpx" , function() {
var pro_cat_m = $(this).val();   
var text =$(this).parent().parent().prevAll('tr').find('td:first').map(function() {
  return $(this).find('option:selected').text();
}).get();
```

Thanks

Comment: Show the code for better view?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Try $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').map(function() { }

Comment: can you fiddle it?

Comment: Your html structure ?

Comment: no, i can't get , if i have 5 tr row ,and ,if  i  directly go to 5 th row means now  i want to show alert msg  previoues  row are not fill(or) empty

Comment: my html structure is only fixed  five tr row inside the table tbody

Comment: Can you plz clearly explain your problem? You can also write in hindi.It will be helpful because I didn't understand your problem correctly but I have created a fiddle. Is it something like this https://jsfiddle.net/og4jLb9b/

Comment: @SuhailAKhtar Thanks, i want to validate previous select box are not empty if i go to select 5th select box here i need to check previous four select box are  not empty

Comment: plz create a fiddle it will help